# How to read access rights from access mask?

Tags: c#, algorithm

User can have the following access rights:

```
Read = 1
Create = 2
Edit = 4
Delete = 8
Publish = 16
Administer = 32
```

When access rights are saved in the database, only one number is used to represent all access rights for that user.

e.g.

```
3 = Read + Create
25 = Read + Delete + Publish
```

How can I get all access rights for a given number (access mask)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var mask = (AccessRights)25;

var rightsForMask = Enum.GetValues(typeof(AccessRights))
                        .Cast<AccessRights>()
                        .Where(x => mask.HasFlag(x));

foreach (var right in rightsForMask)
{
    // displays "1:Read", "8:Delete", "16:Publish"
    Console.WriteLine((int)right + ":" + right);
}

// ...

[Flags]
public enum AccessRights
{
    Read = 1, Create = 2, Edit = 4, Delete = 8, Publish = 16, Administer = 32
}
```

If you're not using .NET4 then the [`HasFlag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx) method won't be available, in which case you'll need to change the `Where` clause to read `Where(x => (mask & x) == x)`.

Answer (score 9):

```
[Flags]
public enum MyFlags
{
    Read = 1,
    Create = 2,
    Edit = 4,
    Delete = 8,
    Publish = 16,
    Administer = 32,
}
```

To declare

```
MyFlags readCreate = MyFlags.Read | MyFlags.Create;
```

To test

```
bool hasRead = (readCreate & MyFlags.Read) == MyFlags.Read;
bool hasEdit = (readCreate & MyFlags.Edit) == MyFlags.Edit;
```